# Why do I get an invalid file error when passing a .get from tinys3 to tarfile.open

Tags: python

```
conn = tinys3.Connection(aws_access_key, aws_secret_key, endpoint=my_endpoint, default_bucket='')
fh = conn.get('somefile.csv.gz')
f = tarfile.open(fh, 'r:gz')
csv_f = f.extractfile('somefile.csv')
```

Why do I get `TypeError: invalid file: <Response [200]>` at tarfile.open()? Am I missing a step after .get?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to connect AWS without specifying bucket - see example https://github.com/smore-inc/tinys3

Comment: Sorry I should have specified I left out the name of the bucket to hide the company. I'll put the parameter back in the OP blank

Comment: So you'll have to see what happens when you'll be uploading it if the connection is successfully established .